# Error while trying to import Keras in Python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build my first ANN model in Python.
I've tried to import Keras in Python 3.7 it gave below error:

```
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

I am now trying to import Keras again in Python 3.6, it's giving me same error.

I've tried upgrading pip, numpy, reinstalled Python and Anaconda based on past recommendations in SO, still it's giving same error. I am running it on Windows 10. Could someone let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you also tell your numpy version, also what are you using for backend in Keras, Tensorflow or Theano, also what are it's versions and then I will see if I can replicate this error.

Comment: numpy version is 1.15.4, using Tensorflow backend. Tensorflow version is 1.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue here is you are trying to install Keras on top of a version of Numpy that doesn't have the functions that Keras requires, that is why it is advised to track your pip packages, I was able to replicate this error with the given versions and solve them by upgrading numpy and tensorflow, if that is not an option due to some reason, you will need to use an Older version of keras.

This error was replicated with current version of Keras(2.2.4), and using mentioned version of numpy(1.15.4) and tensorflow(1.13.1), but it can be rectified by either upgrading numpy and tensorflow, or by using an older version of Keras.

Replicated error

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2019-03-14 09:55:54.418943: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr
```

Solved by

```
pip install -U numpy
pip install -U tensorflow
```

Comment: pip install tensorflow --upgrade --force-reinstall worked for me.